# No space left on device (Linux VM Instance on google cloud )

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create an folder on vm instance however  I am keep getting the error saying the no space .The space storage as follow:

[image]

And the error message is :

[image]

Can any one help me plz

Comment: Why -1  and can you suggest me any solution .....

Comment: your home directory is full, that's what the error message is saying and what the `df` shows

Comment: No dwnVote, but voting-to-close: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate on[su] or [unix.se], but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  ALSO don't illustrate your problem with screen shots, copy/paste data into  Q and then use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your `/home` directory is full and needs to be cleared. To identify which directory this is, go to `/home` and identify which files/directories are taking up space.

```
$ cd /home
$ du -sh *
```

From here, you should be able to drill down and empty files as required.